# Invalid Object error while trying to perform a SQL query

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to make my first steps in databases used with WPF. The problem is that once I start the application, I get an error saying

> Invalid Object - "tblUser"

where `tblUser` is the name of a table.

I made sure that table name is correct, tried creating another table to see whether it changes anything. All the permissions are granted to manipulate the table.

```
private void Submit_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;");

    try
    {
        if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlCon.Open();

        String query = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblUser WHERE Username = @Username AND Password = @Password";

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username",txtUsername.Text);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);

        int count = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());

        if (count == 1)
        {
            MainWindow dashboard = new MainWindow();
            dashboard.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username or password does not exist");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlCon.Close();
    }
}
```

First I create a connection to the database. Next step is I would like to check whether connection is closed, if it is I'm opening it. Then it looks like something went wrong with the SQL query because it seems not to recognise `tblUser` and sees it as an invalid one.

Comment: Obligatory "never store passwords in plaintext" notice.

Comment: Whats the meaning of the `String query = "***SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblUser WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Password"***;` , you have *** inside the string and then *** out of the string

Comment: What's with all the asterisks around your query?

Comment: What's with the asterisks?

Comment: Asterisks are not included in the code, sorry for that.

Comment: just skip the asterisks

Comment: Is it tblLogin or tblUser?

Comment: I wouldn't bother checking the connection state before opening it. You can see that you just created the connection object just above. There's no chance that it's open. That's really only useful when passing the connection object around.

Comment: _"where tblLogin is a name of a table"_ but you're using `tblUser`

Comment: @Fueledbypizza "*just skip the asterisks*" - better: just edit the question and remove them.

Comment: @Fueledbypizza I strongly suggest you *don't* store passwords yourself. You don't need to anyway. You don't need to anyway. Windows *already knows* who the user is. You can use Windows Authentication to connect to the database securely using the current user's identity. If you call `SqlConnection.Open()` without a problem it means the server *already* recognized the user and allowed the login

Comment: @Fueledbypizza if you want to enforce access checks per account, use proper SQL roles and permissions. You can even add Windows Groups to the database so you don't have to explicitly assign permissions for every user.  If you want to store user profile data you can easily get the current user's ID, name or SID trough one of the Security T-SQL functions like [SUSER_SNAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/suser-sname-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: You're connecting to the `master` database - which is odd, because this is really not the place where you should be putting your tables and stuff..... so maybe you just need to connect to **your own** database in the connection string, then your table in that database of your own will be seen and recognized....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*tblUser* is certainly not in the master database. The asterisks are not part of SQL. I am surprised that the error message doesn't complain about that at first

Comment: The error message doesn't mention it because for some reason OP included those here even though they aren't in the actual code. From their comment: "Asterisks are not included in the code"

Comment: Asterisks were my mistake while editing code. Now it's corrected.